# c++ defining enum of different namespace

Tags: c++, enums, namespaces

I have the following header file:

```
namespace First
{
    namespace Second
    {
        class Limit
        {
            public:
                enum Status
                {
                    GOOD,
                    BAD
                };
        }
    }
}
```

Since it's proprietary I have changed the names, and only left the relevant info.

In my own class I have...

First::Second::Limit::Status limit_status = First::Second::Limit::Status::OK;

But I get an error:
error: class First::Second::Limit::Status is not a class or namespace

I am able to declare a variable of that enum, but not set it to any of the values. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
First::Second::Limit::Status limit_status = First::Second::Limit::GOOD;
```

You don't need the `Status` bit. Think of it as defining several `const int`s inside `Limit`, you wouldn't say `Limit::int::GOOD`.

Comment: In other words, `enum` doesn't create a namespace like `class`, `struct`, and `union` do.

Comment: i.e. it ports what's inside to the surrounding scope.

Comment: ahh ok, seems like it differs from java and other languages. Out of curiosity, is there reasoning behind this? The way it is done in java makes the most sense to me, but that might be because I am used to that. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why, but at least they added `enum class` now so it's similar to Java if you use that.

Answer (score 4):

If you have C++11, use `enum class`:

```
namespace First
{
    namespace Second
    {
        class Limit
        {
            public:
                enum class Status
                {
                    GOOD,
                    BAD
                };
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can use `Status` as a scope. If not, you'll have to not include the `Status::` part.